# It's possible to connect a usb midi controller into a midi synthesizer?

Tags: keyboard, midi, synthesizer, midi-controller-keyboard

I do have an usb midi keyboard controller (m-audio keystation 49) and a synthesizer  keyboard (KORG KROSS). I would like to assembly my controller to my synthesizer. However  my controller only have USB port (no midi out port).

Is there any adapter to connect my USB controller into my MIDI synthesizer?

- M-audio ports [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61MYGhigWiL.*SL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61MYGhigWiL._SL1500_.jpg)
- Korg KROSS http://i.korg.com/uploads/Products/Product_Images/USA_Kross_3.png

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/13943/18896 mentions http://www.kentonuk.com/products/items/utilities/usb-host.shtml, which may work if the keystation 49 is 'class compliant'.

Comment: @topomorto , answer this question with this comment and i will accept this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run a Akai EWI-USB into a Yamaha vlm-70 sound module using a raspberry pi and a usb-to-midi converter cable. The linux aconnect utility connects the usb midi input from the EWI-USB to the usb side of the usb-to-midi converter. This works perfectly with no noticeable latency.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, it's called a computer :-)

Like you said, you have an USB MIDI controller. This type of device is designed to be connected to a USB host, i.e. (in general) a computer and used with a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) software.

However you can install a MIDI (standard) port in your computer connecting also to a USB port. The [Roland/Edirol UM-1](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/UMOneMk2) is a commonly used device for this, but there are alternatives from many vendors.

Then you can use a DAW software to route the MIDI messages coming from your controller, through the output port of the USB MIDI port, out to your synthesizer.

If you don't have a DAW software you can use a simpler MIDI host software, there are a few freely available out there. I suggest for example [Hermann Seib's VTSHost](http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm). As the name implies it's specific purpose his to allow the usage of VST plugins outside the context of a fully fledged DAW. But it's perfectly capable to manage several input and output MIDI devices. Don't let the disclaimers and not so professional look of the site fool you, I've been using this software for a number of years and it works great.

Comment: Just saw topo morto's comment above, wasn't aware of this device, it's a simpler alternative than my solution of using a computer. But if a computer with a DAW is already used, then getting a USB MIDI port will be probably less expensive and more readily available, depending on location. Anyway, a couple of different alternatives do choose from.